# How to show 5 additional rows in a table each time using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a table with 30 rows. What I would like to do is display the top 5 rows by defaults and then show 5 more if the use click on "Show 5 More".

so by defaults show only 5 once "Show 5 More" is clicked then display 5 more so now the user see 10 rows. click "Show 5 More" then now you can see 15 rows. so on and so fourth.

How can I do this? is there a jQuery plugin for this?

Comment: you can use datatable plugin. It has pagination.

Comment: I tried using datatables plugin which is great but it does not support colspan and in this case I need "colspan"

Answer (score 1):

## First method: using `append()` function

**HTML**

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Username</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="template">
       <td class="num">5</td>
       <td>Larry</td>
       <td>the Bird</td>
       <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button class="btn">Show more</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
// number of rows seen by default
var n = 5;

// click on the "Show more" button
$(".btn").on("click", function () {
    // how many rows to add?
    var howMany = 1;

    // call ajax, if you use it and the following
    // code will go to ajax callback        

    // add rows
    for (var i = 0; i < howMany; ++i) {
        appendItem();
    }
});

function appendItem() {
    // clone item
    var item = $(".template").clone().removeClass("template");
    // set its data
    item.find(".num").text(++n);
    // append it
    $("tbody").append(item);
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kf78s/)

## Second method: using `fadeIn()/show()` functions

**HTML**

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Username</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="template">
       <td class="num">5</td>
       <td>Larry</td>
       <td>the Bird</td>
       <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- THE HTML IS GENERATED BY JQUERY -->
  </tbody>
</table>

<button class="btn">Show more</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
// ================= GENERATE DUMMY TABLE
var n = 0;
var TOTAL_ROWS = 30;
for (var i = 0; i < TOTAL_ROWS; ++i) {
    appendItem();
}


function appendItem() {
    var item = $(".template").clone().removeClass("template");
    item.find(".num").text(++n);
    item.addClass("table-item");
    item.hide();
    $("tbody").append(item);
}

// ================= SHOW ONLY FEW ROWS BY DEFAULT

var howMany = 5;
showDefaultRows();

function showDefaultRows() {
    var complete = 0;

    $(".table-item").each(function () {

        if (++complete > howMany) {
            return;
        }
        $(this).show();
    });
}

// ================= ON CLICK

$(".btn").on("click", function () {

    var complete = 0;
    var showMore = 5;
    howMany += showMore;
    $(".table-item").each(function () {
        if (++complete > howMany) {
            return;
        }

        $(this).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kf78s/1/)

Comment: Don't believe he is loading anything from AJAX, seems like all rows already exist.

Comment: @AndrewPeacock  Thank for your answer. Your code is appending rows. I am trying to show more. All records are pre-loaded once the page opens but I don't want to show all the records by defaults as uses don't need to see pass 5 but in some cause they may want to see pass 5 so I have this button to show them more if they want to see more.   So i need to show/hide not append. how can i do this? Thank you